# GNU regular expression for partial match

Tags: regex

I have a document with `The SPEAKER (Hon. xxxx yyyy)` and `The President(Hon. aaaa bbbb)`.

How do I match the contents of `SPEAKER` (i.e. `xxxx yyyy`) but not the second `(aaaa bbbb)`?

Comment: Is the only difference the word before the parentheses? And how will you actually be using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Regex for this...

```
$text=~m/\(Hon\.\s*(x{3}\s+y{3})\)/igs;
```

In case of your using a variable for those x and y

```
$x='x';
$y='y';
$text=~m/\(Hon\.\s*($x{3}\s+$y{3})\)/igs;
```

Comment: So xxxx yyyy. same as aaaa bbbb could be anything. I am sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Ya.. Absolutely. Don't think about statics.. Even in programming you can do anything as much as easy... :)